# Dashed lines appear joined when using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Whenever I plot my data in dashed or "--" format, the lines appear partially joined for some reason. Even when I save the figure to file, the dashed lines appear joined as can be seen in the attached image.

I'm just using basic code from some matplotlib tutorials so why would this be happening? I'm using Python 3.6 and Spyder 3.1.4 IDE.

Heres a short snippet of my code from where I start plotting:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, color='black', linestyle='dashed') 
legend = ax.legend(loc='upper left',numpoints=1, frameon = False)
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis="y", tight=False)
y_formatter = plt.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(y_formatter)    
plt.savefig(os.path.join(output_path, "test")+'.png',bbox_inches='tight',dpi=300)
```

[image]

Comment: Some enormous values on the y axis. Just wondering what happens if you divide all the y values by 10^12.  Maybe you'd can post the data for at least one of the bad lines? If it's linear then just the start and end point world do.

Comment: Could it be that your points are not sorted? In this case your line would be drawn forth and back several times and the joined dashes would not be a surprise. You can quickly test this by only using the first and last x-y pairs in you plot command.